# Cannot show alert message on top of anythings else when Scroll appear

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Expected:
[expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boqCB.png)

When scroll appears I cannot set CSS to show an alert message, I already set z-index, position,
It always shows at the bottom, like link:
[current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8cN6.png)

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi Tien, I recommend you to share a snippet with us. So we can see what you try and correct your mistake if we can.

Answer (score 1):

Set the CSS `top` property to 20px. It should work if you have set the `position`.

Comment: Shift around the `20px`  if it's too high up or if it's too low.

Comment: I already set it, but it not working @SafwanSamsudeen